# p-adic ultrametric balloons

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that with p-adic ultrametric : $|.|_{p}=p^{-ord(.)}$ where . is a integer and p is a prime , with $|0|_{p}=0$ if we have balloons $$B(a,R)=\{z\in \mathbb{Z}||z-a|_{p}\le R\}$$  $$B(b,R)=\{z\in \mathbb{Z}||z-b|_{p}\le R\}$$

then they can never overlap.

Proposition: They can never overlap without being the same.

Assume we have two different points y and y' in one ball, if $y\in B(a,R)$ with the strong  triangle inequality $|a+b|_{p}\le sup\{|a|_{p} ,|b|_{p}\}$

now set: $a:=z-y'$ and $b:= y'-y$ so we get : $|z-y|_{p}\le sup\{|z-y'|_{p}. |y'-y|_{p} \}$

So that means $|z-y|_{p} \le R \Leftrightarrow |z-y'|_{p}\le R $ e.g. every point of the ball is a center point so the balloons can never overlap without being the same.

Is this a proof for the proposition? (I never made use of the second balloon...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct and usually the point where most people would stop, but you can complete the proof explicitly to make it clearer how the second balloon is related:

You have shown that for all $y, y' \in B(a,R)$, you have $ B(a,R) = B(y,R)=B(y',R).$ Now suppose there is some intersection between the two balloons, say at $z$. Then since $z$ is in the first ball, by the previous result $ B(a,R) = B(z,R).$ Similarly, since $z$ is in the second balloon, $B(b,R) = B(z,R)$, and thus $B(a,R) = B(b,R)$ so the balloons are the same.